# ElasticSearch Multiple words multiple times containing and or in multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I was trying to build  queries where, I can search in multiple fields. Example:
1. "Criminal Law" and "Act 1999 Vol 2" and "Human Rights"
2. "Human Rights Law" or "Labor Law" and "Chan Mia"

Note: Strings needed to be matched exactly when inside quotation.

I was trying with following Query:

```
   "query": {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query":     "\"Criminal Law\"" or "\"Act 1999 Vol 2\"" and "\"Human Rights\"",
                  "fields":     [ "transcript" ],
                    "operator": "and"
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi_math doesn't support operators in the query text. You need to use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
                "query_string" : {
                  "query":     "\"Criminal Law\"" OR "\"Act 1999 Vol 2\"" AND "\"Human Rights\"",
                  "fields":     [ "transcript" ]
                }
              }
```

Query_string supports a strict syntax. If your query is malformated it will throw error. This can create problem when input is coming directly from user. You can use [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) it is fault tolerant. Though it does not provide all features of query_string it doesn't throw error for invalid input. It will ignore the invalid part of query.